# Can someone explain how this JavaScript code works?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I dont get it... why he used **obj** in this function , can someone explain what it doing.

```js
const yourArray = [37, 32 ,97 ,35 ,76 ,62]
function equalizeArray(arr) {
  let obj = {}, max = 1
  arr.forEach(el => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
          obj[el] = obj[el] + 1;
          if (obj[el] > max) {
              max = obj[el];
            }
        }
        else{
          obj[el] = 1
        }
  })
  return arr.length - max
}
console.log(equalizeArray(yourArray));
```

Comment: Depends on what `equalizeArray` is supposed to do. `obj` is used to count the times each value occurs in the array.

Comment: `max` is the most times any individual element is repeated in the array (which here is just 1, as there are no repeats). I have no idea why this is subtracted from the length in the return value, that number has no particular meaning as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RobinZigmond as far as I can tell: to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equality-in-a-array/problem

Comment: @luk2302 thanks, I see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, the function's purpose is to count the maximum number of same values in an array, and then subtract that maximum number (`max`) from the array's length and return that.

The function uses an object `obj` to store array values as keys, and their repetition count as values to those keys.

The variable `max` keeps track of the maximum repetition, if any key has a value bigger than `max` it gets reassigned.

And then function returns `array.length - max`.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it's so clear.